# Loading full-screen Retina image on iPad causes massive 10 MB spike

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiimage, instruments

My app runs in Instruments taking up approximately 700 KB of Live Bytes on average while running. However, every time it loads a new full-screen image, the memory allocations jump about 10 MB for a second, and then recover to the normal 700 KB level.

This is okay at the beginning, but once it has happened a few times I receive memory warnings and the app quits, even though the total Live Bytes stabilises well under the 1 MB mark.

I have created a test project to see why this is happening. It is a Single View Application with only the following code in the View Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *imgFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"00-bg" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgFile];

    UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [img release];

    [self.view addSubview:backgroundImageView];
    [backgroundImageView release];
}
```

The output from Instruments (Leaks) looks like this:
[image: output from Instruments]

I have tried both ARC and non-ARC, and the only difference is the length of the spike (ARC seems to hold onto the memory for longer).

I have also tried both `UIImage imageNamed:` and `initWithContentsOfFile:` but the results are the same.

Why is this spike happening? And is there anything I can do to avoid it?

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible, will you please try to go through the Call Tree down to the allocation and specify the function that actually causes the spikes ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot find the spike in the call tree because it has already gone before I can check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display them on screen, iOS has to uncompress your images and that's where your spike comes from.

2048 * 1536 = 3145728 pixels. At 4 bytes per pixel that is 12 MB.

Comment: You should also note that this memory usage sticks around, but may be hidden by the Allocations instrument (OpenGL ES textures and other visual elements may not show up in Allocations). You should use Memory Monitor to show the true total memory size of your application.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. Turns out in my main app, the use of `UIImage imageNamed:` was causing memory to leak. So when the OS required 10 MB for image decompression, it wouldn't have enough memory to do so. I've replaced all instances with `initWithContentsOfFile:` and although the spikes are still there, the app no longer crashes.

Comment: I would say that since the decompression memory requirement is slightly less than 10 MB, these particular images must only require 3 bytes per pixel because they have no alpha channel :)